# Calculate the quantity on layer based on price

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to calculate the layer cost of making a cake based on option from the customer.
1 layer cost 320.00 ( set price for 1 layer already)

Additional layer cost 100

In html i have this:

```
<select id="layer" name="layer" onchange="updateTotal()" >
<?php   for( $i=1; $i<100; $i++ ) {
        echo "<option value=$i> $i </option>\n"; }
?> 
</select>
```

In my javascript I have this:

```
function updateTotal(){ 
var optionPrice = 0; 
function cakeLayerPrice(){
          document.getElementById('layer');
          optionPrice += 100;}
}
cakeLayerPrice();

var totalPrice = optionPrice;
document.getElementById('totalPrice').innerHTML = "$ " + totalPrice;
}
```

Apparently the amount won't display if I choose even 1 layer, in my function cakeLayerPrice(), what is the right solution?

e.g. it will display 
if I choose

1 layer = 320.00

2 layers = 420.00 (+100)

3 layers = 520.00 (+100) and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time you're calling *updateTotal()* you're resetting *optionPrice* to 0.

Instead you should get from *layer* select box the layer number and multiply it to 100.

```
function updateTotal(){ 
    var layers = document.getElementById('layer');
    var totalPrice = parseInst(layers.value, 10) * 100;

    document.getElementById('totalPrice').innerHTML = "$ " + totalPrice;
}
```

If nothing is selected, or you did't set a default selected, you could get a *-1* value.
In this case, just update the code to handle the negative values:

```
function updateTotal(){ 
    var layers = document.getElementById('layer');
    var totalPrice = parseInst(layers.value, 10) * 100;

    if (totalPrice > 0) {
        document.getElementById('totalPrice').innerHTML = "$ " + totalPrice;
    }
}
```

This example, avoids even the case your price is 0.

If you have this possibility, just change the code as needed.

Comment: alright i'll try this out. I have lots of functions which are pretty similar. My main function is the updateTotal() where I'll add these functions in the end which works perfectly fine. I just got confused when it comes to layer as well this applies to quantity. Thank you.